# Power BI changing data source from CSV to folder while keeping all measures

Tags: powerbi

I have a Power BI report where I load data from a CSV into a table (Original Table). I want to change the source of the table to a folder that contains multiple CSVs. The issue i'm having is that when I go to change the data source settings of my Original Table I cannot change it to folder. Original Table has many measures and I would like to avoid rewriting them all. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a new query that reads multiple csv from a folder and combines them.
2. Make sure the column names are the same as in your original table.
3. Open both queries in the advanced editor and copy the whole code from the new query to the old query
4. Delete the new query